# Creating simple function to rate potential quality of a basketball game

Tags: functions, logarithms

The concept is relatively simple, but unsure how to implement it. I want an output of a number between 0 and 1 where the inputs are the sum of the ranks of the teams and the point spread.

E.g. Suppose TeamA and TeamB were the #1 and #2 teams ranked in the country and the spread was 0. ∴ sum_rank = 3 and spread = 0. This would be the "perfect game" and should have a score of 1 or .999.

But the sum of the ranks should carry more weight:

Another e.g. #300 TeamA and #301 Team B were playing (sum_rank = 601), and the spread is 1. This would not be a great game because the teams are so bad, perhaps output of like .1.

Yet another e.g. #100 vs. #101 and spread of 0 (perhaps output of .50) is a better game than #1 vs. #100 and spread of 15 (perhaps output of .30).

If someone could get me started on a function, and I can play with the different numbers to weight it according to my likes. Might take some tweaking, but would appreciate the head-start! Thanks.

Comment: I dk what you want this function to do so I can't answer. But I'd like to point out that the point spread is not intended to be an estimate of the likely result but a method of trying to ensure that a nearly equal amount of money is bet on each side .Because bookies pay at best a 100 dollar profit on a 110 dollar successful bet.The spread may change prior to the game, depending on the behavior of bettors up to that moment.

Comment: The most obvious would be $$\frac{3}{\text{sum_rank }+ k(\text{spread})}$$ for some fixed factor $k$, which you could adjust to your fit your desires for the relative strength of point spread vs ranking.

Comment: @user254665: thanks, yes I am very aware of how bookies try to optimize for market behavior and even fooling the public on some lines, but the spread is still the best indicator we have of the likelihood or odds of a team winning. Yes, my function will not be perfect because the spread isn't perfect (nor are even the rankings), but it's still going to be a great indicator of the quality of the game.

Comment: just a thought: I found that a simplified  and  tweaked version of the Elo chess rating system works rather well for predicting the results of National Hockey League  games.

Answer (score 0):

Let $N$ represent the number of teams in the league 
and $R$ represent the sum of the Ranks

then $R_{min}=3$ and $R_{max}=N(N-1)$

let $S$ represent the point spread 
so $S_{min}=0$ and you can decide what to put in for $S_{max}$ 
( since it's basketball you might start with $S_{max}=100$ )

Construct a rating function containing 3 arbitrary parameters as follows ...

$$  T(R,S) = aR+bS+c $$
Get 2 equations for the 3 unknowns by requiring that ...

$$ T(R_{max}, S_{max})=0 \text{ and } T(R_{min}, S_{min})=1 $$

Use these equations to eliminate 2 of the unknowns . 
You will be left with one adjustable parameter which you can use to satisfy your requirement that Rank should carry more weight than spread.

Alternatively you could create a third equation $a=kb$ then you could solve the 3 equations for $a, b, ,c$ and adjust $k$ to satisfy your requirement that Rank should carry more weight than spread.

Expect to get negative values for $a$ and $b$ and a positive value for c.